# CSS3 Animations

Tags: css, css-animations

I've started playing around with CSS animations. Fun!

I've set up this fiddle to practice the idea of wheels on a bus.

http://jsfiddle.net/Dr56H/2/

What's weird is sometimes there is a white space between the two divs as they move down the animation.. Any idea why?

(I only have code for chrome right now)

Comment: I double checked that, and played with them to confirm. They're definitely right. The issue is it works sometimes and then after refreshing, it sometimes doesn't..

Comment: `overflow:hidden` on `.bus` will make it ~1px tall, I can't really explain why its happening though

Comment: It's actually still random after that :/

Answer (score 2):

I did this and it worked.

```
.one {
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:red;
position:absolute;
/* Safari and Chrome: */
-webkit-animation:myfirst .4s linear 0s infinite normal;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you remove animation from .one as in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dr56H/3/) it's not there anymore